How and why should we properly assign signs to objects in motion in opposite directions?
On a foggy day, two car drivers spot each other, when they are just 80 m apart. They are traveling at 72 km/h and 60 km/h respectively towards each other. Both of them simultaneously apply brakes, which retard both the cars at a rate of 5 m/s​​​​​​2.  Now my question is, that in this question, shouldn't the acceleration and velocity of the second body be positive and negative , like the second object is retarding that means it is acceleration is in other direction which we have taken as positive but in the solution acceleration of both of the bodies is taken as negative


Yes, you are correct. The acceleration of car no. 2 will slow down the car's speed, meaning it will bring the speed to zero. Since the speed is given a negative sign then the acceleration must be positive. If the solution you are given uses another sign of the acceleration, then the speed must also have a different sign.

Yes you are right, once the convention has been decided that the "left to right" direction is positive and the "right to left direction" is negative then all quantities should be expressed using this convention.
So, in this question,
$$u_1 = + 72kmph = + \left(72 \times \frac{5}{18}\right) m/s = + 20 m/s$$
$$a_1 = -5 m/s^2 $$
and
$$u_2 = - 60kmph = - \left(60 \times \frac{5}{18}\right) m/s = - \frac{50}{3} m/s$$
$$a_2 = +5 m/s^2 $$
Now using equation of motion,
$$ v^2 - u^2 = 2as $$
Assuming $s_1$ and $s_2$ to be the displacement of car 1 and car 2.
We get,
$$v_1^2 - u_1^2 = 2a_1s_1$$
and
$$v_2^2 - u_2^2 = 2a_2s_2$$
At the condition that $v_1 , v_2 = 0$
We get,
$$(0)^2 - (+20)^2 = 2(-5)s_1$$
and
$$(0)^2 - \left(-\frac{50}{3}\right)^2 = 2(+5)s_2$$
$$\implies s_1 = 40m$$
$$\implies s_2 = -\frac{250}{9}m$$
If initial position of car 1 $(d_1)$ is taken to be $0$ then initial position of car 2 was$(d_2)$ =+80 m
Final position = Initial Position + Displacement
$$\implies d_1^{final} = d_1 + s_1 = 0 + 40 = 40m $$
$$\implies d_2^{final} = d_2 + s_2 = 80 + \left(-\frac{250}{9}\right) = \frac{470}{9}m = 52.22m $$
So, the cars will not crash and the distance between them when they stop will be $12.22m$.
You can verify this against the answer that may be provided to you.

Velocity is not a scalar quantity (not just a number) but a vector. I.e.,
$$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix} v_x\\ v_y \\ v_z\end{pmatrix}$$
Now, there are two situations where velocity that is just a number comes up

You may be interested in the absolute value
$$ \Vert \vec v\Vert := \sqrt{ v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}$$
E.g. the absolute velocity of a car. By definition, this value is always positive. In particular, $\Vert \vec v\Vert = \Vert - \vec v \Vert$ since the velocities $\vec v$ and $-\vec v$ only differ in direction. Note that in general $\Vert \vec v_1 + \vec v_2 \Vert \neq \Vert \vec v_1 \Vert + \Vert \vec v_2 \Vert $

1.You may be interested in a one dimensional problem. E.g.,assume that all velocities are pointing in $x$ direction, i.e., $v_y = v_z = 0$. In this case, you can write any velocity of interest as
$$\vec v_i = v_i \cdot \vec e_x = v_i \cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Where the number $v_i$ can be both negative and positive. Note that in this case $\vec v_1 = \vec v_2$ if and only if $v_1= v_2$. In particular, $\vec v_1 + \vec v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ if $v_1 = -v_2$.


... shouldn't the acceleration and velocity of the second body be positive and negative ?

Yes. If we take the positive direction (for both velocity and acceleration) to be to the right then Car 1 has positive velocity. Since Car 1 is slowing down it has negative acceleration. Car 2 is heading in the opposite direction so it has negative velocity. Since Car 2 is slowing down, its acceleration is reducing the magnitude of its negative velocity, so its acceleration is positive.
